# Did the Room of Requirement work after Crabbe’s Fiendfyre?

Tags: harry-potter

Did the Room of Requirement work after Crabbe's Fiendfyre?

Or did it just destroy one of the forms that The Room of Requirement can take on (the Room of Hidden Things), but not explicitly the others?

Comment: Unknown. Though I like to imagine Trelawney going back there a year or so later to deposit some sherry bottles and getting the fright of her life.

Comment: @TheDarkLord - I'm sure you would.

Answer (score 14):

Ron wondered the same thing.

> *‘Where’s Ginny?’ he said sharply. ‘She was here. She was supposed to
> be going back into the Room of Requirement.’*
>
> ***‘Blimey, d’you reckon it’ll still work after that fire?’** asked Ron,
> but he, too, got to his feet, rubbing his chest and looking left and
> right. ‘Shall we split up and look –?’*
>
> <sub><sup>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sup></sub>

There doesn't seem to be a definitive answer in the canon. The room isn't accessed again in the books or follow-up play.

---

It may interest you to know that Pottermore poses much the same question on its own [page about the Room of Requirement](https://www.pottermore.com/features/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-room-of-requirement), again without conclusion.

> **The Room may no longer exist**
>
> *Once Harry has retrieved the diadem Horcrux, the room is overrun by Fiendfyre started by Malfoy's crony Vincent Crabbe. The flames killed
> the foolish Crabbe, but Ron suspects the Fiendfyre was so powerful, it
> might have damaged forever the room that wizards need most.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Everything you need to know about the Room of Requirement](https://www.pottermore.com/features/everything-you-need-to-know-about-the-room-of-requirement)</sup></sub>

Comment: [What follow-up play?](https://xkcd.com/566/)

Comment: @Randal'Thor the Cursed Child

Comment: @KyleV - [Whoosh](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svtLfoGH19c&feature=youtu.be&t=16s)

Comment: *Pottermore poses much the same question on its own page about the Room of Requirement, again without conclusion* Well if that's all Rowling said about it, than Pottermore couldn't really write anything else.

Comment: Thematically, the Room should regrow itself and reappear unexpectedly after a few decades; hopefully, Hermione documented it for a new generation of students.

Comment: @Randal'Thor A large portion of the world was confounded into believing that there was a sequel.